# Compiling android project with kotlin on TeamCity fails

Tags: android, continuous-integration, kotlin, teamcity, travis-ci

My build step uses the gradle build in template from TeamCity but unfortunately I get:

```
[16:29:22][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin] Using kotlin incremental compilation
[16:29:48][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin] Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful
[16:29:48][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin] java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
[16:29:48][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin]   java.io.EOFException
[16:29:48][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin]   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:229)
[16:29:48][:presentation:compileLocalDebugKotlin]   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
```

Any ideas on why I might get this?

Comment: show your build.gradle files please

Comment: wow that's cool. two days after commenting on this I ran into the same issue... see my answer for my solution

Answer (score 6):

By default, the Kotlin compiler executes in its own process daemon. Pass this configuration to Gradle when running on CI to compile Kotlin in the same build process:

```
-Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process"
```

Disabling the Gradle daemon is also common practice in CI environments:

```
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false
```

One might expect that the Gradle daemon property would also disable the Kotlin compiler runner daemon, but that's not what currently happens. [GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/compilerRunner/GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt) only considers the `org.gradle.daemon` property *after* the `kotlin.compiler.execution.strategy` property. If the execution strategy is not defined, the runner uses the `"daemon"` strategy by default:

```
val executionStrategy = System.getProperty(KOTLIN_COMPILER_EXECUTION_STRATEGY_PROPERTY) ?: DAEMON_EXECUTION_STRATEGY
if (executionStrategy == DAEMON_EXECUTION_STRATEGY) {
    val daemonExitCode = compileWithDaemon(compilerClassName, compilerArgs, environment)

    if (daemonExitCode != null) {
        return daemonExitCode
    }
    else {
        log.warn("Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.")
    }
}

val isGradleDaemonUsed = System.getProperty("org.gradle.daemon")?.let(String::toBoolean)
return if (executionStrategy == IN_PROCESS_EXECUTION_STRATEGY || isGradleDaemonUsed == false) {
    compileInProcess(argsArray, compilerClassName, environment)
}
else {
    compileOutOfProcess(argsArray, compilerClassName, environment)
}
```

Explicitly setting the execution strategy to `"in-process"` will get you to `compileInProcess()` regardless of the Gradle daemon configuration, however, you may need to disable both daemons on CI servers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. A little comment about sources where execution strategy is chosen. I guess source code of [GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/compilerRunner/GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt) was refactored, so code example that you mentioned here moved to another class - [GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/compilerRunner/GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. It was not connected to Kotlin, though.

I had to disable the gradle deamon (it's not recommended on CI servers anyway).

In teamcity you can e.g. do it by adding `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false` to the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Comment: This is correct. Also starting with Gradle 3.0, Gradle is daemon by default which means the KotlinCompileDaemon will stick around.

Comment: Note from the link: Since Gradle 3.0, we enable Daemon by default and **recommend using it for both developers' machines and Continuous Integration servers**. However, if you suspect that Daemon makes your CI builds unstable, you can disable it to use a fresh runtime for each build since the runtime is completely isolated from any previous builds.

Comment: @lovis will the environment variable override the gradle.properties values? We'd like to enable the daemon in dev environments but disable it on the CI server.

Comment: @RyanR afaik the gradle.properties win over the environment variables, but I'm not 100% sure (and definitely no expert). Sorry :/